# FileHandler is not registering or updating

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I have tried adding, removing the FileHandler, it's not working. Also, after changing(URL) in the existing FileHandler, the url still points to the old URL. The existing FileHandlers are working fine but no new changes are picked.

I have followed the doc *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online*

It is not visible and even not reflecting in the refreshUrl

GET *https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/apps?forceRefresh=1*

or via the Admin refresh

GET *https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/apps?adminForceRefresh=1*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

File handlers are cached in two ways - locally in the browser and on the server. These caches have a timeout of 24 hours, meaning it can take up to 48 hours for updates to a File Handler manifest to appear for users.

When developing a file handler, it's useful to be able to reset the local cache for your account to see the latest file handlers.

To reset the cache, you should:

- Submit the below request to refresh the server-side cache.
- Clear the browser's local data
- Close the OneDrive browser window.
- Open the browser window and navigate back to OneDrive

  **GET https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/apps?forceRefresh=1**

  **Authorization: Bearer {access-token}**

**Note:** The {access-token} for this request must have either the **MyFiles.Write** or **Sites.Read.All** scope for the SharePoint application.

This request will tell OneDrive to refresh the cache, but will return the current values from the cache. The cache may take several seconds to repopulate, depending on the number of applications installed in the user's tenant.

In addition to the server-side cache of installed file handlers, the OneDrive web app also has a session cache of file handlers. This cache is automatically cleared when the browser session ends (when the last OneDrive tab is closed).

for more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/reset-cache?view=odsp-graph-online)